# Unity build APK failed. Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

When I build my Unity project APK, I get an error about gradle build failed. Digging into the log I see it's because the bintray GET request return 502 error:

`Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/ironsource-mobile/android-sdk/com/facebook/android/facebook-applinks/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway`

I'm using Facebook SDK 11.0.0 for Unity. Unity version 2019.4.17, build target Android ARM64. In Preference > External Tools, I set Gradle to gradle 6.8

Is there any way to fix this?

Here's the full error log:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
D:/UnityEditors/2019.4.17f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "D:\Android\gradle-6.8\lib\gradle-launcher-6.8.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleDebug"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':launcher:preDebugBuild'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':launcher:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:[11.0, 12).
     Required by:
         project :launcher > project :unityLibrary
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://dl.bintray.com/ironsource-mobile/android-sdk/com/facebook/android/facebook-applinks/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://dl.bintray.com/ironsource-mobile/android-sdk/com/facebook/android/facebook-applinks/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/ironsource-mobile/android-sdk/com/facebook/android/facebook-applinks/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
]
stdout[
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <d76da2c9a45b4b02b93f56ae560b1d44>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <d76da2c9a45b4b02b93f56ae560b1d44>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <d76da2c9a45b4b02b93f56ae560b1d44>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <d76da2c9a45b4b02b93f56ae560b1d44>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <d76da2c9a45b4b02b93f56ae560b1d44>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <d76da2c9a45b4b02b93f56ae560b1d44>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <d76da2c9a45b4b02b93f56ae560b1d44>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <d76da2c9a45b4b02b93f56ae560b1d44>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <d76da2c9a45b4b02b93f56ae560b1d44>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <d76da2c9a45b4b02b93f56ae560b1d44>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <d76da2c9a45b4b02b93f56ae560b1d44>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <d76da2c9a45b4b02b93f56ae560b1d44>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <2f1c602eae0d45c293fff3e3aef759fa>:0)
UnityEditor.DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer(BuildPlayerOptions)
VersionIncrementor:BuildPlayerHandler(BuildPlayerOptions) (at
```

Comment: Have you check this? [Bintray is shutting down; What should I do?](https://plugins.gradle.org/docs/bintray)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to download an old version of the facebook adapter (as mentioned in the conment - bintray is shutting down)
IronSource latest integration shows that the artificat is now downloaded from a new location:
https://developers.is.com/ironsource-mobile/android/mediation-networks-android/#step-2

Replace your current integration and follow the unity integration guide as explained here: https://developers.is.com/ironsource-mobile/unity/mediation-networks-unity/#step-1

It will resolve you're conflict.